# cakephp 1.3 disabled htmlspecialchar in textarea

Tags: cakephp

how disabled htmlspecialchar?
The text now looks like this:

name: `1e&lt;br /&gt; username: 2&lt;br /&gt; age:3`

How get normal text (`name: 1<br/> username: 2 <br> age: 3`)?

```
<?php echo $form->input('spec_info', array('label'=>false, 'type' => 'textarea', 'escape' => false));?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'escape'=>false option.

```
echo $this->Form->input('notes', array('type' => 'textarea', 'escape' => false);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1433/textarea